# Magento 1.9: Product image popup window

Tags: magento-1.9, extensions, product-images, modal-popup

I need a product image popup on my Magento website.

So I see this extension https://marketplace.magento.com/swissup-tm-easylightbox.html  and installed it. But it is not working.

I want product image popup like this. How can I get a popup like this?

which code i need to write in `template/catalog/product/view/media.phtml`

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try below extension for the product image popup.

> https://templates-master.com/magento-easy-lightbox.html

Hope it helps!!!

Comment: I downloaded the extension . But there is no extension key to install . how can i activated this extension through ftp

Comment: Do you've admin details of the website?

Comment: yes. i have the admin details

Comment: Can you please share the screenshot where the licence key is required for this extension?

Comment: please check the question section

Comment: You can download the package (download latest version 3.2.0) from the extension account dashboard after login https://templates-master.com/downloadable/customer/products/ and extract the package. After extracting, you can transfer the app, js, and skin folder from FTP to your website root.

Comment: there are too many files to upload right ? also i have to edit some files right like app/code/community/TM/CatalogConfigurableSwatches/etc/config.xml like thi ? just for conforming

Comment: Yes, usually the extension has too many files in them depends on their functionality.
You can compare and edit those files if the file has anything important which is using on the website.